# Simulating values from a random variable that is a sum of other random variables

Tags: random-variable, simulation

$X$ is $\mathcal N(0,4)$, $Y$ is $\mathcal N(0,5)$, $Z = X + Y$

I need to simulate 1000 values for each of these variables, $X$,$Y$,$Z$.

I have simulated 1000 values for both $X$ and 1000 values for $Y$.

When simulating 1000 values for $Z$, should I use the values already simulated for $X$ and $Y$?

Or should I simulate new values for $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Without context, your question really can't be answered. If you want, then of course you could generate 3 independent samples, one for `X`, one for `Y`, one for `Z`. As a guess, you probably don't want the samples to be independent, but how could we actually know that? You never said what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like the other answers so far have not been completely clear on why you **must** reuse the same samples that you obtained for $X$ and $Y$: this is necessary to obtain a sample of $(X,Y,Z)$ which has the correct **joint** distribution.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent (that wasn't explicit in the question), then:
 $$\text{Cov}(X,Z) = \text{Cov}(X,X+Y)=\text{Cov}(X,X)=\text{Var}(X)=4$$

We then have $\text{Cor}(X,Z) = 2/3$, so $X$ and $Z$ are definitely not independent. Then, intuitively, the method you use to sample $Z$ must use your existing samples for $X$ and $Y$ in one way or another.

If we compare both approaches (using the same $X$ and $Y$, or new $X$ and $Y$):

```
set.seed(123)

x <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(4))
y <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(5))
z <- x + y

x_new <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(4))
y_new <- rnorm(1000, 0, sqrt(5))
z_new <- x_new + y_new

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,z, main = paste0("Same sample: sample correlation = ", format(cor(x,z),digits=3)))
plot(x,z_new, main = paste0("New sample: sample correlation = ", format(cor(x,z_new),digits=3)))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

We get the following plots:[image]

On the left, reusing the same sample of $X$ and $Y$ yields a correlation between $X$ and $Z$ which is roughly what we expected (2/3). It's not shown here but it also has the correct joint distribution of $Y$ and $Z$, and the full $(X,Y,Z)$.

On the right, the correlation is roughly zero. Using new samples of $X$ and $Y$ completely destroys the dependence structure with $Z$.

Answer (score 4):

If $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=2)$ and
$Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=\sqrt{5}),$
then $Z = X+Y \sim 
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=\sqrt{4+5} = 3).$

If you simulate many values of $X,$ then the a histogram
of those values imitates the density function of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=2).$ 
Also, the sample mean of the many values $X_i$ will
be $\bar X \approx  0$ and the their standard
deviation will be $S_X = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 \approx 2.$
Using R for the
simulating, summarizing, and graphing, we have:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(10^5, 0, 2
summary(x); sd(x)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-8.359695 -1.349914 -0.014586 -0.005547  1.339879  8.318011 
[1] 1.994003  # aprx sigma.x = 2

hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Histogram of Sample from NORM(0, 2) with Density")
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 2), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

Similarly, for $Y,$ but without the graph, we get:

```
summary(y); sd(y)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-9.607853 -1.505329 -0.006414  0.001022  1.500837 10.620498 
[1] 2.235846  # aprx sigma.y = sqrt(5) = 2.236
```

Finally, if you add simulated vectors of values `x` and `y`, you will simulate the distribution of
$$Z = X+Y \sim 
\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=\sqrt{4+5} = 3),$$
Thus, a data summary of `z` will show $\bar Z \approx 0$ and $S_Y \approx 3.$

```
z = x + y
summary(z);  sd(z)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-13.299918  -2.027446  -0.003853  -0.004525   2.010361  12.703835 
[1] 2.994405  # aprx sigma.z = 3

hist(z, prob=T, col="skyblue2",  ylim=c(0,.13), 
     main="Histogram of Sample from NORM(0, 3) with Density")
curve(dnorm(x, 0, 3), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

*Notes:* In case you are interested in details of R, here are a few.

(1) Normal probability functions in R, (such as `rnorm` to simulate and density `dnorm`, use the standard deviation $\sigma$ instead of the variance $\sigma^2.$

(2) If you are going to superimpose a density function on a histogram, then the histogram needs to be a 'density histogram'. This requires parameter `prob=T` in `hist`.

(3) The R procedure `curve` to plot a function requires the argument of the function always to be written as `x`--- regardless of the context.

(4) The parameter `ylim=c(0,.13)` of the procedure `hist` makes the plotting window tall enough to
accommodate the density curve without cutting off
its mode.

(5) When you write `x + y` in R for two vectors of the same length (here length $10^5 = 100,000)$ then R takes the
element-wise sum, yielding a vector of the same length.
The table below shows the first six out of 100,000 such additions.

```
head(cbind(x, y, z))
              x          y          z
[1,]  0.7539442  1.0037551  1.7576993
[2,]  0.6030967  0.2978469  0.9009436
[3,] -2.1960463  3.9858896  1.7898433
[4,] -2.2608118 -3.0263022 -5.2871140
[5,] -5.5930686  3.8786439 -1.7144247
[6,]  1.4411470  0.3790924  1.8202394
```

Answer (score 2):

If $Z=X+Y$, and you have $X$ and $Y$, then just sum them, that's the simulation for $Z$.